# Subsequences in Coq

Tags: coq

I am a new to proof assistants and recently got stuck on the subsequence exercise from the [chapter on inductively defined propositions](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html) from Logical Foundations.

The exercise asks to define an inductive proposition `subseq` for lists of natural numbers and prove several claims. While trying to prove transitivity, I defined a function `subseqb : list nat -> list nat -> bool` and tried proving that it is equivalent to `subseq`. I am only able to prove the following direction: `forall {l1 l2 : list nat}, subseqb l1 l2 = true -> subseq l1 l2.`

All of my attempts at proving the converse fail, and seem to boil down to my inability to prove the lemma `cons_cancel_subseq` below. I tried induction on `subseq` hypotheses, lists and list lengths in various orders, as well as using list reversal.

Can someone point out how to prove either of the incomplete results below?

```
Require Import List.
Require Import Nat.
Require Import Bool.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
  | hl1 : subseq [] []
  | hl2 lst1 lst2 (H: subseq lst1 lst2) : forall (x : nat),
      subseq lst1 (x :: lst2)
  | hl3 lst1 lst2 (H: subseq lst1 lst2) : forall (x : nat),
      subseq (x :: lst1) (x :: lst2).

Fixpoint subseqb (lst1 l2 : list nat) : bool :=
  match lst1, l2 with
    | [], [] => true
    | [], y :: ys => true
    | x :: xs, [] => false
    | x :: xs, y :: ys => match x =? y with
                            | true => subseqb xs ys
                            | false => subseqb lst1 ys
                          end
  end.

Theorem subseq__subseqb : forall {l1 l2 : list nat},
    subseq l1 l2 -> subseqb l1 l2 = true.
Proof.
  Abort.

Lemma cons_canel_subseq : forall {x : nat} {lst1 lst2 : list nat},
    subseq (x :: lst1) (x :: lst2) -> subseq lst1 lst2.
Proof.
  Abort.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your lemma `cons_cancel_subseq`, your issue has probably to do with performing induction on predicates which are not applied on variables. You can try and use `dependent induction` for such a setting (you'll need to import `Program.Equality` from the standard library for that though).

But a better idea is to obtain your lemma as a corollary of another one where the arguments to `subseq` are variables. I suggest the following:

```
Definition tail (l : list nat) : list nat :=
  match l with
    | [] => []
    | x :: l' => l'
  end.

Lemma subseq_tl {lst1 lst2 : list nat} :
    subseq lst1 lst2 -> subseq (tail lst1) lst2.
```

Note, though, that your are taking a very long detour: you should be able to prove transitivity of `subseq` much more direcly. I would suggest the following:

```
Theorem subseq_trans {l1 l2 l3 : list nat} :
  subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l2 l3 -> subseq l1 l3.
Proof.
  intros H1 H2.
  induction H2 in l1, H1 |- *.
```

ie, induction on the second proof of `subseq`, *generalizing over any subsequence of `l2`*.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/amarmaduke/6376237dbc35d5746b50cb21906c6158) is a complete proof of `cons_cancel_subseq`. There is a lot going on, and it can probably be simplified with someone more familiar with Coq. Let me explain the high-level details.

The basic structure of the proof follows this sequence:

- Destruct the `subseq` evidence, the `hl1` and `hl3` cases should be trivial.
- Now, if the underlying data looks like an `hl2`, then we need to dig into the lists because it must be the case that `l2 = prefix ++ x :: suffix`, and we need to process the prefix to obtain the matching `x`. Thus, we need to perform induction on `l2`.
- From there we get a trivial base case and `l2 = a :: l2'`, now we consider the cases when `x = a` and `x <> a` separately.
- For both situations, we destruct the `subseq` evidence again, potentially recursing using the inductive hypothesis.

Some important technical things to note:

- In order to destruct the evidence in a way that is going to be useful we want to make it look like `subseq a b` for variables `a` and `b`. Of course, we don't have that, but we can fix it by using the `remember` tactic on the arguments to `subseq`. This will setup the evidence in a more amenable way *and* record the necessary equalities for us. This is similar to `dependent induction` but I personally prefer this method.
- I use the `pose proof` tactic to introduce new facts, it is like forward reasoning. Coq is great at backward reasoning but a lot of the time you just want to learn a new fact and this tactic helps with that.
- Because we introduced a lot of equations we have a lot of extra variables, the `subst_list` tactic breaks down an equation of the form `x :: l1 = y :: l2` into the obvious equalities and substitutes them all away. This is useful to get rid of the extra equations when they are no longer needed.

As has already been noted the route you're taking is harder than what is needed to prove transitivity. But, it's also a lot more fun. I think your `subseq_subseqb` theorem will require the same skills used to prove the `cons_cancel_subseq` lemma, and these skills are pretty handy when working with inductive propositions.